# Why the database become so slow when it have 1 million rows?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

When we have 1 million lines in a single table, dealing with anything about this table becomes very slow with the specified commands like `Select * From TBL_USERS Where ID = 20` but if we deal with any other table it becomes faster and easier as normal and this indicates that the defect is not in the database.
Is there an explanation for this phenomenon and solution?

Comment: "... this phenomenon" I'm not sure that's the correct word here.

Comment: select *  brings back every column. It results in a table scan most likely. 1 million rows is a lot to scan (to return as well). If you would only list out the columns you need, it would be faster (presuming you have covering indexes). I'm guessing you don't have an index on that ID either...

Comment: @scsimon 
There's another ways to get some row between all this rows ?

Comment: You have a million rows in your user table? This question is so vague and so broad.

Comment: I don't know what you are asking @MohamedIbrahim. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide us with the DDL (create table, create index) scripts for TBL_USERS.

Comment: @SeanLange yes i have 1 million rows in the Table
that make any command execute so slow

Comment: @scsimon
 i have 1 million rows in the Table that make any command execute so slow

Comment: @MohamedIbrahim, do you have an index on the `ID` column? How many rows are actually returned?

Comment: @DanGuzman 
what mean a number of row ?
that columns is Generate Auto Number and have a primary key.
ID of row 1 = 1
ID of row 2 = 2
and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically there are two things that contribute to the time it takes to process a query:
How many rows SQL Server has to read to satisfy the conditions of the query. If all the rows have to be read (and possibly if the pages the data is on bought into memory) this is called a scan and takes a while. If SQL Server has an index and only needs to read one or a few pages this is much faster and is referred to as a seek.

The second part of a query is how many rows (and columns) have to be returned. If millions of rows have to be pushed across a lan this will take time. This is why it is a good idea to avoid using the * (as in select * from tableA) and to try to use where conditions as much as possible which will narrow down the number of rows being returned.

Comment: Thank you @bejamin moskovits.
How i can select this rows in datagridview like pages
Like 100 rows in one page and the second the same too ?

Comment: It sounds like you want to use the  OFFSET and     FETCH NEXT  parts of TSQL. Here is a good guide on how to use it: https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch You can also research tsql pagination.

Comment: Thank you for this information.